# Using custom control with Google Maps KeyDragZoom - how to activate drag zoom?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, keydragzoom

I am using KeyDragZoom

http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/keydragzoom/2.0.5/docs/examples.html

I would like to put the control somewhere else on the page, not within the google map.  I can not figure out how to do this.  I would even be fine with having a button off the map that would just trigger a click of the button within the map. **How can I activate the drag zoom?**

P.S. I am using the Visual Drag Zoom Control instead of using a keyboard key like shift.

Comment: It seems this functionality is essentially missing in KeyDragZoom. They need to add some method to actualy activate it. Would be a nice feature request!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up doing this `$('img[src=http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ftr/controls/dragzoom_btn.png]').click();`

Thanks hookedonwinter

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer assumes that the zoom control is on the map.  If visualEnabled is false, the dragzoom_btn image will not exist.

A hack that seems to work:

```
function onZoomClick() {
   var myKeyDragZoom = map.getDragZoomObject();
   myKeyDragZoom.hotKeyDown_ = !myKeyDragZoom.hotKeyDown_;
}
```

When clicked, the zoom mode is turned on.  When clicked again or the rectangle is drawn, zoom mode is automatically turned off.