# Google Maps v3 Custom Controls - Interact with control outside of map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using a google maps custom control.  I would like a text link outside of the map (on another place on the page) to interact with the control.  Basically I want to be able to trigger a click on the custom control.

Does anyone have advice or assistance on how this can be accomplished?

This also relates to [Using custom control with Google Maps KeyDragZoom - how to activate drag zoom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7197462/google-maps-dragzoom-how-to-put-control-not-in-map) , decided to make a question more general.

Comment: Can you show the code you already have?  What does the custom control do?

Comment: Here is an example of the same usuage I am using.  You will see a small control below the zoom controls.  I want to do the same behavior as clicking on that from html outside the map.

http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/keydragzoom/2.0.5/examples/visual.html

Comment: I think this generalization is not good, because it has only the dirty solution presented... it is better to solve it based on the operation you actually need to do, as in your [example with keydragzoom](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7197462/684229). And there is certainly some functionality missing..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try directly selecting it by source:

`$('img[src=http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ftr/controls/dragzoom_btn.png]').click();`

Comment: This ended up working exactly as needed, I was hoping there would be a method for doing this directly with the control, but this will work.

Comment: $('img[src="http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ftr/controls/dragzoom_btn.png"]').click();

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to make KeyDragZoom turn on/off when you click on a link outside the map, you can set the `onclick` event on the link to run a function like this:

```
function toggleClickZoom() {
    var myKeyDragZoom = map.getDragZoomObject();
    myKeyDragZoom.buttonDiv_.onclick(document.createEvent('MouseEvent'));
}
```

Comment: Looking for the method in their docs now.

http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/keydragzoom/2.0.5/docs/reference.html

Comment: Have not been able to find the method needed.

Comment: What are you hoping to find a method to do?

Comment: To be able to trigger the custom control from outside the map.

Comment: What do you mean by "trigger"?

Comment: Have you read the original question?  In the example, http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/keydragzoom/2.0.5/examples/visual.html , there is a control under the zoom control fro the drag zoom.  I want to be able to turn on and off the drag zoom from outside the map.

Comment: OK, I've updated my answer with the two lines of code that seem to be working for me.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to create custom zoom in and zoom out buttons outside the map:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <style type="text/css">
      html { height: 100% }
      body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
      #map-canvas { height: 60%; width:60%; margin:20px auto; border:1px solid; padding-left:100px; }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=ADD-YOUR-API-KEY-HERE&sensor=false&region=AU">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

function HomeControl(controlDiv, map) {

 google.maps.event.addDomListener(zoomout, 'click', function() {
   var currentZoomLevel = map.getZoom();
   if(currentZoomLevel != 0){
     map.setZoom(currentZoomLevel - 1);}

  });

   google.maps.event.addDomListener(zoomin, 'click', function() {
   var currentZoomLevel = map.getZoom();
   if(currentZoomLevel != 21){
     map.setZoom(currentZoomLevel + 1);}

  });

}
var map;

/**
 * The HomeControl adds a control to the map that simply
 * returns the user to Chicago. This constructor takes
 * the control DIV as an argument.
 * @constructor
 */

function initialize() {

  var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 15,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.90224, 151.20215),
    panControl: false,
    zoomControl: false,
    streetViewControl: false,
    overviewMapControl: false,
     mapTypeControl: false,
     mapTypeControl: false,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, mapOptions);

  // Create the DIV to hold the control and
  // call the HomeControl() constructor passing
  // in this DIV.
  var homeControlDiv = document.createElement('div');
  var homeControl = new HomeControl(homeControlDiv, map);

  homeControlDiv.index = 1;
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(homeControlDiv);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);    
</script>

</head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
    <div id="zoomout" style="border:1px solid; width:150px; heoght:50px; cursor:pointer; margin-bottom:20px;">ZOOM ME OUT</div>
    <div id="zoomin" style="border:1px solid; width:150px; heoght:50px;cursor:pointer;">ZOOM ME IN</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer assumes that the zoom control is on the map.  If visualEnabled is false, the dragzoom_btn image will not exist, nor will buttonDiv_.

Until external controls are officially supported, this hack seems to work:

```
function onZoomClick() {
   var myKeyDragZoom = map.getDragZoomObject();
   myKeyDragZoom.hotKeyDown_ = !myKeyDragZoom.hotKeyDown_;
}
```

When clicked, the zoom mode is turned on.  When clicked again or the rectangle is drawn, zoom mode is automatically turned off.